# Restore state of a mysql database after tests

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a website that has a lot of unit tests, each needing the database to be in some 'default' state. Right know I'm destroying the database with each test and loading the default state using an SQL script. And it's very slow. So I thought that it would be useful if I could save that default state and restore the database to it at the beginning of each test. 
Is this possible ? If not, why could I do to accelerate the process ? Right know I drop the entire database and re-create it. If I dropped only the rows wouldn't that improve the performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up the database to default state before all of your tests and then wrap each test in a transaction. After test finishes, you just rollback the transaction.

This approach is especially suitable when you want to run your test in concurrence, as they do not depend on any shared state.

However there are use cases where it does not fit. For example when there are multiple processes accessing the database involved in a test scenario, which is a common case in integration tests.

The real world example of such situation: Test runner (process #1) setting up data in database and phantomjs running in the background making request to app server (process #2). You can't both test runner and app server share a single database transaction.

Comment: +1 This is so much more sensible than my suggestion!  Although it does, of course, require use of a storage engine that supports transactions and prevents use of any [statements that cause an implict commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/implicit-commit.html).

Comment: Hi does this work reliably in real world complex use cases ? Are you using it for long now ?

Comment: @vishal it is reliable and in fact is a common practice (for example in ruby/rails world). but it's also worth noting that this approach is not suitable in all cases. I added more info about this to the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work if your app uses transactions already internally since MySQL cannot nest transactions.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could hide your incumbent tables behind temporary ones:

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo
   PRIMARY KEY (a),
   UNIQUE  KEY (b),
   FOREIGN KEY (c) REFERENCES bar (c)
   SELECT a, b, c FROM foo
   ```

   Once the connection drops, the temporary table will be discarded (thus leaving behind only the original, unaffected table).
2. Use [dependency-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to simulate a database, to connect to a testing database, or otherwise perform any requisite initialisation (such as creating the above temporary tables).